# BreadCrumb. Why does it show the whole list instead just the page is opened and the one before?

Tags: html, css

I need to fix my BreadCrumb in my simple website, it shows the whole list not just the one is opened with the pages before. Like, it should show  HOME,  HOME>About Us, HOME>Gallery, HOME>Contact US. But just show the whole breadcrumb list the whole time.

Can you help me? thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <img style="width: 370px;" src="pictures/logo.png" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourmenu/ourmenu.html">Our Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus/contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <nav id="mainMenu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="ourmenu/ourmenu.html">Our Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus/contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%;" id="slider">
        <br /> <br />
        <figure />
        <img src="pictures/image1.png" alt> <img
            src="pictures/image2.png" alt> <img src="pictures/image3.jpg"
            alt> <img src="pictures/image4.jpg" alt> <img
            src="pictures/image5.jpg" alt> <br /> <br />
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: #b30000; height: 250px; width: 500% px">
        <br />
        <p>
        <h1>
            KFC<br> 299 Westmoreland St.<br> Dublin 2<br> Eircode:
            D02 HK35<br> Ireland
        </h1>
        </p>
        <br />
        <h1>
            <p>
                Tel + 353 1 9999999<br> Fax + 353 1 6666666<br> Email
                KFC@.ie
            </p>
        </h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica;
    color: white;
    padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 1cm;
    line-height: 1.3;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: Brack;
    padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 1cm;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-align:center;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: Brack;
    padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 11.5cm;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: Brack;
    padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 4cm;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: Brack;
    padding-right: 6.5cm;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-align:right;
}

*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.menu {
    list-style:none; 
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0; 
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px
}

.menu li{
    position:relative; 
    float:auto; 
    border-right:1px solid #c0c0c0; 
}

.menu li a{color:#333; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 20px; display:block;}

.menu li a:hover{
    background:#b30000; 
    color:#fff; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #CCC; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 10px 0 #ccc; 
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #fff; 
}

.menu li ul li{
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0; 
    display:block; 
    width:150px;
}

#mainMenu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    list-style:none;
}
#mainMenu li {
    float:left;
}
#mainMenu a {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:150px; /
    text-decoration:none; 
}

@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 

div#slider { overflow: hidden; }

div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }

div#slider figure { 
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: middle;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
 div.vertical-line{
    width: 1px;
    background-color: silver;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px ridge silver ;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 12px;   
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin-top: 6px; 
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
    resize: vertical 
}


input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #b30000;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #b30000;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #808080;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 45%; 
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: Calibri, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;

}

body {
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.gallery {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.gallery li {
    margin: 5px;
}

.gallery img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
}

.modal:target { 
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.imagen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.imagen a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.imagen a:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 2;
}

.imagen img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 7px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cerrar {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.map {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.divFooter {
    background-color: #b30000;
    height: 270px;
    width: 500%;
    float: left;
}

/* Style the list */
ul.breadcrumb {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Display list items side by side */
ul.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline;
}

/* Add a slash symbol (/) before/behind each list item */
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    content: "/\00a0";
}

/* Add a color to all links inside the list */
ul.breadcrumb li a {
    color: #0275d8;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a color on mouse-over */
ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
    color: #01447e;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any logic to the HTML like PHP to determine what page you're on? The list of links in the breadcrumbs won't change if there is no back-end functionality to hide/show the right links depending on the page.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Can you help me please?

Comment: You'd need to learn some kind of back-end development language like PHP or Python. There's lots of sites that have quick start guides. Search via Google and some decent sites should come up at the top.